# Qual é a diferença entre "achada" e "chã" como tipos de terrenos?

Tags: significado, diferenças, sinônimos, cabo-verde

Na Ilha de Santiago em Cabo Verde, há muitas zonas cujos nomes começam com "Achada" ou "Achadinha", por exemplo "Achada Santo António" e "Achada Grande". Estas são as zonas com mais elevação dos seus arredores.

Nas ilhas de São Vicente e Santo Antão, em vez de "Achadas", encontram-se muitas "Chãs", por exemplo "Chã de Alecrim" e "Chã de Monte Sossego". Outra vez, estas são zonas que ficam mais ou menos no alto.

**Em português, no contexto de terreno,** qual é a diferença entre "chã" e "achada"? São sinónimos? No dicionário, encontrei a palavra *planalto*, ‘terreno plano e alto’, em definições de ambas as palavras.

<sub>(Já sei que estas palavras têm outros significados que são distintos, e que português não é a língua materna da maioria dos cabo-verdianos.)</sub>

Comment: Nem sequer conhecia essas designações...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quer [*Chã* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ch%C3%A3) quer [*achada* (Aulete 2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/achada) são extensões de terra plana; mas enquanto a achada é sempre num alto, a chã tanto pode ser em terras baixas como altas. Basicamente ambas as palavras caíram em desuso, sobrevivendo essencialmente em nomes de lugares.

Correspondente ao substantivo *chã* temos também o adjetivo [*chão, chã* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ch%C3%A3o), do latim *planus*, que significa ‘plano, simples’ etc. Mas também quase não é usado hoje em dia, e muita gente nem sequer sabe que a palavra tem este sentido. (Vejam [esta pergunta sobre o adjetivo *chão*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/the-adjectival-use-of-ch%C3%A3o).) Eu, que cresci numa comunidade rural, ainda ouvi falar de “terra chã.” Mas existem em Portugal para cima de uma dúzia de povoações com o nome [*Vila Chã* (Wikipédia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vila_Ch%C3%A3) e ainda *Chão disto* e *Chã daquilo*. Por exemplo [Chã de Alvares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A3_de_Alvares), [Chã da Casinha](https://catalogoagrotur.pt/produtor/cha-da-casinha), [Chão do Rio](http://www.toprural.pt/Casa-rural-aluguer-completo/Ch%C3%A3o-Do-Rio-Turismo-De-Aldeia_117282_f.html). Também se encontram [nomes destes no Nordeste brasileiro (Wikipédia).](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A3_(desambigua%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

*Achada* eu nem conhecia. Mas vem em vários dicionários. O Houaiss define-a como ‘planície no alto de um monte; planalto’, e explica que vem do latim **aplanāta*, derivado do verbo latino tardio *applāno*, que significa ‘aplanar’, com evolução provável **aplanāta* > *achãada* > *achaada* > *achada*. A palavra está atestada no século XV:

> […] avia umas Aldeas, em que poderiam morar até cem pessoas em tres Povorações, as quais eram n’achaada da serra
>   [Gomes Eanes de Zurara, *Crónica do Conde D. Pedro de Menezes*, 1462 (edição de 1790).](https://books.google.pt/books?id=d8lTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA356&dq=achaada&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBmMbTv8rVAhXEnRoKHSqhCZA4MhDoAQjpAjAw#v=onepage&q=achaada&f=false)

Na ilha da Madeira, colonizada uns quarenta anos antes de Cabo Verde, existem também imensas povoações com o nome [*Achada de* qualquer coisa (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achada_(desambigua%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

Answer (score 4):

Ambas as expressões são pouco usadas actualmente em Portugal. Geralmente localidades com essas características são denominadas "Alto de" ou "Monte de". Exemplo: Altinho do Lobo.

No Alentejo existem algumas pequenas localidades com Chã no nome, que geralmente denomina um local plano.